# Existe algum editor ou ide que tenha opção de live preview para Php

Tags: ide, editor

Alguém sabe algum editor ou ide que tenha recurso de live preview para php, no caso um live preview que exiba automaticamente o resultado no navegador, sem que seja preciso salvar o arquivo, ou seja a ligação seja ao vivo e direta, conforme digito um código já apareça simultaneamente
Procuro um assim para Php, 
Para html,css e js o Brackets esta funcionando para mim,
Mas para Php esta dando erro
Já tentei vários editores e ides não deu certo 
Pode ser um que tenha live preview parcial( que tenha que salvar o arquivo Php)

Answer (score 2):

Olha, eu também não conheço um que faça em tempo real mas de forma parecida você pode instalar o plugin **Browser Sync** para o **VSCODE** (na verdade qualquer IDE com terminal).

Eu fiz com o terminal Node.Js colocando:
`npm install -g browser-sync`

Depois de concluido a instalação você pode ir no seu projeto aberto no VSCode e pressionar `CTRL + "` para abrir um terminal e assim digitar:

`browser-sync start --proxy localhost/nomedoseuprojeto --f . server`

**browser-sync start:**  inicializa;

**--proxy nomedocaminho**: como é PHP e o browser-sync utiliza a porta `:3000`, você precisa especificar o caminho local dele.

**--f .**: seta a pasta atual do projeto para abrir.

Sempre que você der um `CTRL + S` em alguma mudança, ele vai recarregar a página rapidamente e exibir as mudanças. É ideal caso esteja usando 2 telas onde uma fica a sua IDE e na outra fica o navegador.

Espero ter ajudado.

Att